# How to organize reference to different types of input elements in Selenium Framework

Tags: java, selenium

I'm building my Selenium+Java automation framework. I'm on a point where I need to design the approach concerning how I will refer to different types of elements on a page (text fields, radio buttons, drop-down lists, etc.)

Each of mentioned fields will have unique methods. Some methods will be general for all fields types.

Would id be better to create a separate class for each field type (Button.class, TextField.class, etc) and methods suitable for it? Or maybe its better to create some general kinda GeneralElement.class and put all possible methods there?

Please, advise on approach, some links and references on best practices will help too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [POM](http://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html) framework. It is a design pattern to create Object Repository for UI elements. It basically keeps the UI elements separate from the logic.

The idea is to have a page class for each of the pages in your application, these page classes will contain the respective web elements on that page. You can also create getters and setters as per the need.

Reference links: [ToolsQA](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/), [SeleniumEasy](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/page-object-model-framework-introduction)

Comment: what if I want to implement logging for each interaction with each element? Following these easy examples I'll have to write log text for each method on the page...and I find this redundant. I'm thinking about separating elements and pages, and using elements when creating methods for a certain page.

Comment: What is your need? POM is a very neat way to structure your tests. Also, logging is as per the need anyway.

Comment: To be more precise - I need to log each click on element, log each time text field is filled with a text ( sendKys method), in other words any possible interactions will all available elements types. I need the best approach. What you sugggested really makes sense, but I need to design logging at some deepper abstract layer then in Page methods.

Comment: for logging you can use Apache log4j2 in your test methods after each interaction with your elements, e.g. click, assert, select.etc. Logging for each element can be done with POM and without as well.